# datalog_frontend.cpp ..\src\shell\datalog_frontend.cpp(20): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream': No such file or directory

Tags: windows, visual-c++, build, z3, nmake

I want to install z3 on windows 10
I clone the project and do python scripts/mk_make.py
and at the end, I want to run nmake in the build directory of the project but I got the following error

> 

datalog_frontend.cpp
..\src\shell\datalog_frontend.cpp(20): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream': No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cl /c /nologo /Zi /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /EHsc /GS /Gd /std:c++17 /W3 /WX- /O2 /D _EXTERNAL_RELEASE /D NDEBUG /D _LIB /D UNICODE /Gm- /GF /G
y /TP  /MD -I..\src\api -I..\src\tactic\portfolio -I..\src\tactic\smtlogics -I..\src\ackermannization -I..\src\model -I..\src\ast\macros -I..\src\ast\rewriter -I..\sr
c\ast -I..\src\util -I..\src\math\polynomial -I..\src\math\interval -I..\src\math\automata -I..\src\params -I..\src\solver -I..\src\smt\params -I..\src\tactic -I..\sr
c\ast\simplifiers -I..\src\ast\euf -I..\src\ast\normal_forms -I..\src\ast\rewriter\bit_blaster -I..\src\ast\converters -I..\src\ast\substitution -I..\src\qe\lite -I..
\src\qe\mbp -I..\src\math\simplex -I..\src\ast\proofs -I..\src\sat\sat_solver -I..\src\tactic\core -I..\src\ast\pattern -I..\src\parsers\smt2 -I..\src\cmd_context -I.
.\src\parsers\util -I..\src\tactic\aig -I..\src\tactic\bv -I..\src\tactic\arith -I..\src\sat -I..\src\math\dd -I..\src\math\grobner -I..\src\sat\tactic -I..\src\sat\s
mt -I..\src\smt -I..\src\smt\proto_model -I..\src\solver\assertions -I..\src\ast\fpa -I..\src\math\lp -I..\src\nlsat -I..\src\nlsat\tactic -I..\src\smt\tactic -I..\sr
c\muz\fp -I..\src\muz\base -I..\src\qe -I..\src\muz\clp -I..\src\muz\transforms -I..\src\math\hilbert -I..\src\muz\dataflow -I..\src\muz\tab -I..\src\muz\rel -I..\src
\muz\bmc -I..\src\tactic\fd_solver -I..\src\muz\ddnf -I..\src\muz\spacer -I..\src\tactic\ufbv -I..\src\tactic\fpa -I..\src\tactic\sls -I..\src\math\subpaving\tactic -
I..\src\math\subpaving -I..\src\math\realclosure -I..\src\opt -I..\src\cmd_context\extra_cmds -I..\src /Foshell\datalog_frontend.obj ..\src\shell\datalog_frontend.cpp
' : return code '0x2'

> 

g++ version is 11.2.0 and python 3.11.2
thanks for any help

I try to reinstall the c++ compiler
nmake version is 14.35.32215.0

Answer (score 0):

This strongly suggests your compiler installation is problematic; probably not correctly installed/configured. See [search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=Cannot%20open%20include%20file%3A%20%27iostream%27&client=safari&rls=en&sxsrf=AJOqlzUXjbwb0AB7eIZKw_gOHzeDYF4X1Q%3A1678985061930&ei=ZUcTZOGwOMCK0PEPkae_4Aw&ved=0ahUKEwih98vh8uD9AhVABTQIHZHTD8wQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=Cannot%20open%20include%20file%3A%20%27iostream%27&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwA0oECEEYAFAAWABg6QVoAXAAeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQDIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) for some guidance.

Having said that, why do you need to compile z3? Unless you'll be working on the source code of z3 itself, this is almost never needed. You can get a binary release for any platform at:

- https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/releases

And, if you are adventurous, you can even get nightly builds:

- https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/releases/tag/Nightly

So, if you really have to compile, I'd suggest reinstalling your compiler infrastructure. However, if you just want to use z3, then get a binary from one of the above links.